# how to keep device enrolled in android management API after factory reset?

Tags: android, mdm, android-management-api, emm

I am developing a EMM solution for my company using android management API. I am enrolling a device by creating enrollment token and generating enrollment QR code. Everything working well my device is enrolling with my enterprise policy in fully managed mode. But the problem is when device is hard reset or when user reset the device. After passing FRP security device is not enrolling again with my enterprise.

I searched a lot and come to the point that this can be possible using Zero Touch Enrollment. But I do not how will it work. Does anyone know how does zero touch enrollment work or is there any other solution to keep device enrolled in Android Management API even after hard reset or reset.

Answer (score 0):

[Zero Touch Enrollment](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#zero-touch_enrollment) automatically re-enrolls Android devices in your enterprise, addressing your concern about unenrollment after a reset. Zero Touch requires the devices be purchased from an authorized [zero-touch reseller](https://androidenterprisepartners.withgoogle.com/resellers/). Note that even though the device stays enrolled in zero touch after a  factory reset, the user data will be deleted. For more information, you may refer to this [documentation](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7514005?hl=en).